# Elixir: Why do I get "undefined function" error?

Tags: compiler-errors, elixir, ecto

The Elixir compiler gives me "undefined function changes/0" in the third line of the function:

```
  def ignore_empty(changeset) do
    cond do
      %{valid?: false, changes: changes} = changeset when changes == %{} -> 
        %{changeset | action: :ignore}
      true -> changeset  
    end    
  end
```

Why is that? I mostly copied this code from Ecto.Changeset documentation of the cast_assoc function [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant to use `case`, e.g.

```
def ignore_empty(changeset) do
  case changeset do
    %{valid?: false, changes: changes} = changeset when changes == %{} ->
      %{changeset | action: :ignore}
    _ ->
      changeset
  end
end
```

The reason you are getting "undefined function" is because when the expression is getting expanded, that happens to be the first error the compiler encounters. It's valid to put an expression in a `cond`, so other than the reference to an undefined function `changes` the other thing which it would fail on is the use of `when`. In any case, that appears to be the issue here.

Comment: Thanks, bitwalker, you are right, I was confused because in the documentation the changeset argument to the case expression gets through the pipe operator and I thought there was a cond expression, my fault.